# Почему отображается только псевдоэлемент before, а after - нет

Tags: html, css, псевдоэлемент

Пытаюсь добавить "птичку" к моим будущим "спойлерам" через псевдоэлементы `:before` и `:after` но в итоге отображается только before, ПОЧЕМУ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**HTML**

```
<ul class="open">
  <!-- <li class="active"> <a href="/"><span>Перфоратор</span></a> </li> -->
  <li class="has-sub">
    <a href="/about_us.html">О нас</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="has-sub">
        <a href="/about_us/istoriya-kompanii/">История компании</a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="/about_us/istoriya-kompanii/test-1/">Тест 1</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="/about_us/istoriya-kompanii/test-nazvanie-bolshoj-dlinny/">тест название большой длинны</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="/about_us/attestaty/">Аттестаты</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/about_us/podtverzhdayushie-dokumenty/">Подтверждающие документы</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-sub">
    <a href="/services.html">Услуги</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="has-sub">
        <a href="/ekskovator.html">Аренда спецтехники</a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="/uslugi/arenda-spectehniki/ekskavator-pogruzchik/">Экскаватор-погрузчик</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="/uslugi/arenda-spectehniki/samosval/">Самосвал</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="/uslugi/arenda-spectehniki/gidromanipulyator/">Гидроманипулятор</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="/uslugi/arenda-spectehniki/avtobetonosmesitel/">Автобетоносмеситель</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="/uslugi/stroitelstvo/">Строительство</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/uslugi/vodosnabzhenie/">Водоснабжение</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/uslugi/otoplenie/">Отопление</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/uslugi/santehnika/">Сантехника</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/uslugi/elektrika/">Электрика</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="/portfolio.html">Портфолио</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
  <li><a href="/#contacts">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
 li.has-sub::after,
  li.has-sub::before
   {
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    position:absolute;
    transition: 0.5s transform;
    top: 25px;
    right: 20px;
  }
```

**UPD:** Еще псевдоэлементы применились не ко всем элементам `.has-sub`, только к первому уровню вложенности.

Comment: Они же у тебя одинаковые. Просто накладываются один на другой. Видно "последний"...

Comment: @ksa На скрине в инструментах разработчика видно, что существует только before. Плюс ко всему, псевдоэлементы применились не ко всем элементам класса .has-sub

Comment: @ДенисГудойть программа делает ровно то, что вы говорите ей делать, а не то, что вам хочется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение:** Оказалось был прописан `display: none;` для after.

Answer (score 0):

> На скрине в инструментах разработчика видно, что существует только before. Плюс ко всему, псевдоэлементы применились не ко всем элементам класса

Вот смотри я сделал пример на твоих стилях. Но слегка поменял позиционирование псевдоэлементов, дабы они были видны.

Все они теперь видны и у каждого элемента они есть.

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
li.has-sub::after,
li.has-sub::before {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s transform;
  /*
  top: 25px;
  right: 20px;
  */
}
li.has-sub::after {
  top: 25px;
  right: 20px;
}
li.has-sub::before {
  top: 25px;
  right: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='has-sub'>Тест</li>
  <li class='has-sub'>Тест</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Я понимаю твое предположение, я в начале так тоже думал, но дело в чем-то другом. Мой after невиден не из-за того, что он находится под before, его вообще нету! (см. скрин) Скорее всего он чем-то перекрывается. У меня в коде есть много других псевдоэлементов, может быть они конфликтуют.

Comment: @ДенисГудойть, тогда тебе остается только убрать все лишнее и потом постепенно добавлять. Смотреть что же повлияет на твои стили.